# Как сохранить файл в память телефона?

Tags: android

Есть папка raw с аудиофайлом, по клику на кнопку нужно этот файл сохранить в папку на телефоне. Пытаюсь для начала хотя бы папку создать, не выходит.

```
int chooseButton(int id) {
    switch (id) {

        case R.id.buttonSave:

            File folder = new File( getContext().getFilesDir(), "Folder");
            if(folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(folder.exists()){` вместо этого должна быть проверка "если папка **не** существует"

Comment: даже без проверки папка не создается

Comment: `File folder = getContext().getDir("Folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` - и система сама создаст эту папку.

Comment: Разрешение на чтение/запись имеется?

Comment: Разрешения на запись и чтение есть, папка все равно не создается.

Comment: Запускаете на эмуляторе? вполне возможно что SDCard подмонтирован в readonly.

Comment: Также любые операции с файлами на главном потоке не желательны.

Comment: А как Вы, собственно говоря, определяете, что эта папка не создалась?

Comment: Тестирую на телефоне xiaomi. Папку пытаюсь найти через проводник. В качестве примера я ориентируюсь на похожий пример с гитхаба SoundRecorder и там папка создается и ее видно в проводнике.

Comment: В поток эту операцию помещу, но сперва нужно добиться результата создания папки и перемещения туда файла из ресурсов.

Comment: Эту папку через проводник Вы не увидите - Вы создаёте её в приватной директории приложения, а не в памяти, доступной пользователю. Начальную информацию по теме можно почерпнуть в доках: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: `if (folder.exists()) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Папка существует");
    } else {  Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Папка не существует");}` - вот так можно проверить, что папка создалась (смотреть в LogCat)

Comment: спасибо woesss,по ссылке документацию уже изучал, не могли бы вы меня носом ткнуть в мануал, как именно создать папку видимую для пользователя?

Comment: Можете начать отсюда: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage, но что бы лучше понять что к чему найдите хорошую статью или учебник, только посвежее.